# Running Windows inside Ubuntu

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu

How can I launch the entire Windows operating system inside Ubuntu. Something similar to Parralel Desktops. Free, please.

Comment: I don't think this is a question for SO.  Try http://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: Voted to migrate, but the answer is [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is virtualization.  There are MANY tools for hosting virtual machines.  Ububtu has [information specific](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/server/virtualisation) to it, so you might start there.  Other common options are [virtual box](http://www.virtualbox.org/), [vmware](http://www.vmware.com/), and [xen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen), among many others.  All of these have free options.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing the opposite (an entire Ubuntu box inside of Windows) via http://www.virtualbox.org/

The same thing will work for your case (Windows inside Ubuntu).

[image]